# Is this sequence based on the Fibonacci numbers a prime generator?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the Fibonacci sequence $\text{fibo}(n)$ and the fractions

$$ A(n) = \frac{\text{fibo}\left(n^2\right)}{\text{fibo}(n)^2} = \frac{b(n)}{c(n)},$$

where the fractions $\frac{b(n)}{c(n)}$ are in reduced form.

Now, it appears that for all $n > 4$:

1. If $c(n) = 1$, then $b(n)$ is of the form $2^q p$ where $p$ is a prime.
2. If $c(n) > 1$, then either $c(n) $ or $b(n)$ is of the form $2^q p$ where $p$ is a prime.

So this formula generates a prime for every $n$.

A weaker conjecture is that this holds for the cases when $n$ is a prime.

**Are these conjectures true? How can we prove them?**

Comment: For $n=6$, $c(n)=4$, $b(n)=3^3\times17\times19\times107$. If I understood correctly, this should be a counterexample to your stronger conjecture.

Comment: Yes but C is a multiple of 4 @ URL

Comment: Also 6 is not a prime !! @ URL

Comment: note that we have the explicit formula for the $n$-th Fibonacci number $$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-(-1)^n\phi^{-n}}{\sqrt5},$$ where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$. This may help

Comment: @mick : The Question has "every $n$" and "$n > 4$", not "every prime $n$", so the Question as written is required to work for $n = 6$.

Comment: Why is $A$ here?  You never use $A$ and, except for discarding common factors of $b$ and $c$, never use the fraction $b/c$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For $n=19$, a prime, we have $$\frac{F_{n^2}}{\left(F_n\right)^2}=\frac{297695973435970582594631907579321477163892921001085193295076858332955181}{4181}.$$

The numerator and denominator are odd, the former is divisible by $6567762529$, and the latter is divisible by $37$. So, both of your conjectures are false.

Comment: Props to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFibonacci%5Bn%5E2%5D%2FFibonacci%5Bn%5D%5E2%2C%7Bn%2C4%2C30%7D%5D) for helping me find this.

Comment: Hmm thank you. It is weird how often this works though. For n = 23 and n = 29 it holds again. Perhaps you can modify the conjecture ? Maybe it fails miserably for very large n ... I will test some more numbers. Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe we should expect any pattern of primes to pop up here. And "most" large numbers are not prime. So, I conjecture that in fact, this fails for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: It fails for 103 too. There we have 3 prime factors. Not many factors though

Comment: I will modify my conjecture in a new question , if the tests are well. I will accept this one +1. This was quite easy though , feel free to answer another of my questions :)

Comment: @mick I think this is less weird than you might think; $F_n\mid F_{n^2}$, which immediately shrinks the size of the numbers involved. When you start talking about restricting to prime $n$, you eliminate several other possible factors from either side, because 'most' small factors can't divide $F_{kp}$ for any $k$.